# Unable to send data to FirebaseFirestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to send data from my Xcode app project to Firebase. Basically, I am making an app for messaging and the messageData is not going to my Firebase Firestore.

Error Info:

```
Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}
2022-12-12 10:18:25.317458+1300 ChatMat[2586:21468] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at messages/X4FzU24jmKueNaFUOnKB failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Here is some info about my machine:

M1 Mac

macOS 13.1

Xcode 14

Cocoapods 1.8.4

⠀

Cocoapods also refuses to update to the latest version 1.11.3 and throws an exit code "1" I am unsure of how I can solve this, and if this is the problem then please help me fix it.

I also do not understand what the error means so I would need some explanation. I am a beginner-ish at using cocoapods with Swift.

Comment: Check your rules, you don't have permission

Comment: @loremipsum How do I do that

Comment: Google firestore rules

Comment: @loremipsum What do you mean by that? How can I check my rules?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: @loremipsum link did not work :(

Comment: the recommended solution didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the rules to as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution beats having a person tell you in the comments that there is no solution and you have to hire someone.

Comment: I will set this as solved tomorrow!